Performance Improvement while running Merge on a Delta Table via Spark on Databricks (Scala)
I have about 500 Delta Tables indexed on an id column and partitioned on date and hour. I need to perform a set of transformations on an hourly/daily basis. During each run (i.e. performing transformations once), I am updating approximately 200-220 million rows in every table. Each table has 200-250 columns out of which at maximum 150 columns will be updated.
My current code is similar to
deltaTable.as("df")
    .merge(
    transformedDf.as("transformed_df"),
    "df.id = transformed_df.id AND df.timestamp = transformed_df.timestamp"
    )
    .whenMatched()
    .updateAll()
    .execute()

Sample schema:
id (string), timestamp (timestamp), date (string), h (string), attr1, (string), attr2 (string) .... up to 250 columns. 

I am not using any partition columns and neither am performing any batching of updates explicitly.
I switched from compute optimized clusters to storage optimized ones on Databricks since merge operation involves heavy I/O. I also enabled Deletion Vectors and Photon Acceleration on DBR.
The current performance is still very bad ~ 4 hours to run on each table. I need to get that down to ~ 2 hours.
Can the community suggest any optimizations / changes to the code which I can employ for better performance?

Can you please post your query plan?  Text version via explain(true).  Also you mention it's partitioned on date and hour but use a timestamp field?  Can you show sample schemas?


I'm not sure if I can post the query plan.
Yes the table is partitioned on date and hour but the primary key for the table is the composite of id and timestamp.
Added sample schema in the question.
I was able to find out the most of the time is spent in finding the files that are to be written. Even more than the re-write itself.


is there a reason why you are not explicitly then filtering on the partition fields (e.g. df.date = transformed_df.date and df.hour = transformed_df.hour)? (Spark cannot know those fields are also present in timestamp)  Also replaceWhere would be better suited it seems

timestamp is the server time. It's a completely separate column which is granular at a millisecond level. I use it to make the composite key since one id can have multiple records but each record will have different timestamp. Also, why is replaceWhere preferred over merge?

so is your partitioning date and hour using the same technical timestamp at all or are they unrelated business fields?   (If they are unrelated then your data is effectively unpartitioned and is probably doing table scans for every change, again the plan would show this).  Using string's for id's indexed or otherwise will have performance issues, you need to introduce fields which are easier to filter out at the parquet level as well (e.g. if you are not partitioning on parts of your id then your id's rows are likely in different files)

timestamp is a business field. Not partitioning on id as well. The table however is already partitioned on date and hour. The files like in the prefixes as s3-bucket/date=yyyymmdd/hour=hh/xyz.parquet

sorry I clearly wasn't very clear, is timestamp completely unrelated to the hour and date partitions?

Yes. It is completely unrelated.

Have you tried Liquid clustering? https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-clustering.html Consider clustering by id and timestamp as those are the fields you use in the query
